# Report Viewer control changes font on print / print preview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reporting-services

I've created a pretty nicely designed form/report with an ssrs project, but I'm trying to print it through winforms using the [ReportViewer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but when I try to print it (or when i switch to print preview), for some reason it'll change its font to some weird looking font.
Note: I tried to preview it on the designer and within winforms on my local computer, so there should be no difference in behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't plan to make this a  Q&A-style but in middle of writing my question i figured it out :-)

Within the `InitializeComponent()` method contained within the `form.designer.cs` file you'll find that visual studio is setting the [Control.Font Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Windows.Forms.Control.Font%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) which causes  the control to get these properties at the time of printing.

[image: form.designer.cs]

So all i needed to do is to comment it out.

Please see my code example below.

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.reportViewer1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer();
        this.btnRender = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.tbPickList = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.cbImmidiatePrint = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.btnPrint = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // reportViewer1
        // 
        this.reportViewer1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        //this.reportViewer1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.reportViewer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 54);
        this.reportViewer1.Name = "reportViewer1";
        this.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Reports/PackingSlips/BestBuy";
        this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri("http://ssrs1/reportserver", System.UriKind.Absolute);
        this.reportViewer1.ShowToolBar = false;
        this.reportViewer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(999, 641);
        this.reportViewer1.TabIndex = 0;
    }
```

Comment: i don't know why but when I did this in vb.net -the font still comes up different than it is on the report. This is frustrating

Comment: Sorry @Bobski but i don't have this project any more, but you should know that nothing happens by itself, you just need to find the line of code that does it...
Another piece of advice, i found crystal reports to be way more usefull when it comes to programming printable forms, i'm not sure if this is your intent here...

Comment: i know nothing happens by itself - i commented mine out and same thing. Thanks

Comment: How about trying to explicitly enter your font there and see if it works?